# Move item to first array position in <cfloop> if x=true

Tags: jquery, arrays, coldfusion

I've got a CFC performing a query via AJAX to get a list of image information/paths to display on my page. In my table I have a boolean column `main` to indicate if the image is the main image and thus displayed above all the other images.

Since I'm accessing the query results via AJAX, I need to create an array of the data before returning it to the page where my javascript function loops over the returned data and constructs the `<img>` tags.

How can I get either my CFC or my javascript loop to recognize the `main` boolean and move that image to first position for display on my page?

Here's my CFC:

```
<cfquery name="project_images">
  select path, title, alt, main from tbl_images where pid = #projects.pid#;
</cfquery>
  <cfloop query="project_images">
  <cfset imgStruct = structNew()>
  <cfset imgStruct["path"] = path>
  <cfset imgStruct["alt"] = alt>
  <cfset imgStruct["title"] = title>
  <cfset imgStruct["main"] = main>
  <cfset ArrayAppend(imgArray, imgStruct)>
</cfloop>
<cfset local.response["images"] = #imgArray#>
<cfreturn local.response>
```

And my jQuery function:

```
$('.project_class').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var theclass = $(this).attr('id');
    var cat = 'planning';

    $.getJSON("../cfc/projects.cfc?returnFormat=json&method=getProjects",
        {"theclass":theclass, "cat":cat},
        function(response){
            $('#portfolio_item').html(response.html);
            var imageData = response.images;
            $.each(imageData, function(i, item) {
                $('#portfolio_item').append('<img src="..' + item.path + '" />');
            });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is sort the images within your SQL. Use a `CASE` statement to assign the `main` record a higher sort order than the others.

```
   SELECT CASE WHEN main = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS SortNum
          , path
          , title
          , alt
          , main 
   FROM  tbl_images 
   WHERE pid = <cfqueryparam value="#projects.pid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
   ORDER BY SortNum
```

Or you could check the `main` flag within the loop and use `arrayPrepend` instead of `arrayAppend` when the flag is true.

Comment: The SQL is BRILLIANT! Thank you. That's actually the way I wanted to handle it, I just wasn't sure how. And, great reminder on the `<cfqueryparam>` tags. I always use them when moving my code into production. Thanks again!